# Why does printf leave some random characters in the main function? [C program]

Tags: c, printf

I want to get info of someone in the getInfo function.

If I print the **name** when I'm **IN** the getInfo function, it prints it out correctly, but after that in the main it leaves some random characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* getLine(){
    char *line = malloc(256);
    fgets(line, 256, stdin);
    if ((strlen(line) > 0) && (line[strlen (line) - 1] == '\n'))
        line[strlen (line) - 1] = '\0';
    return line;
}

void getInfo(char* name,char* place,char* days[]){
    printf("Type in your name:\n");
    name = getLine();

    printf("%s",name);                      // <---- THIS PRINTS OUT CORRECTLY
}

int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{
    char* name = (char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
    char* place = (char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
    char* days[5];

    getInfo(name,place,days);

    printf("%s\n",name);                   // <----- THIS LEAVES SOME CHARACTERS
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
C:\Users\Felhasznalo\Desktop>a.exe
Type in your name:
Peter Smith
Peter Smith`\┴
```

These " `\┴ " characters are what I'm talking about. The first print in the function prints it well, but in the main it gives these ghost characters.

Why are these written out?
Thanks.

Comment: `line[strlen (line) - 1]` -> You need to check if `strlen(line)` is at least 1

Comment: And check the return value from `fgets`

Comment: And also: don't call strlen() three times, when atmost one is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are replacing the 'name' pointer that your `main` function passes to `getInfo()`. This is because `getInfo()` calls `getLine()`, which itself creates a **new** character array, and returns a pointer to this buffer to `getInfo()`.

Inside `getInfo()`, this is printed correctly (as you note); however, the `main` function passes a **copy** of the `name` pointer (i.e. *by value*) - and this is not (cannot) be changed by the `getInfo` function. So, in `main` you are printing out an *uninitialized* character array (`name`).

There are several ways to fix this. One would be to pass the `name` (and, presumably, `place`) argument(s) to `getInfo()` as a **pointer to a pointer**, when you will need to de-reference this inside that function; like so:

```c
void getInfo(char** name, char** place, char* days[])
{
    printf("Type in your name:\n");
    *name = getLine();
    printf("%s", *name);
}
```

Then, in your `main`, you: (a) don't need to allocate memory for `name` (and `place`), as this is done by the `getLine()` function; (b) pass the **address** of the `name` pointer to `getInfo()`. Like this, for example:

```c
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    char* name;// = (char*)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    char* place;// = (char*)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    char* days[5]; // Don't know what you want to do with this!
    getInfo(&name, &place, days);
    printf("%s\n", name);
    // Don't forget to free the allocated buffers:
    free(name);
//  free(place);
    return 0;
}
```

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

Answer (score 0):

`name = getLine();` in `getInfo()` does not affect `name` in `main()`.

Try returning `name` from `getinfo()` and in `main()` assign `char *name = getline(...)`.

---

Aside: Alternative code for `getline()`

```
char* getLine(){
  char buffer[256];
  if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }
  size_t len = strlen(buffer);
  if (len > 0 && buffer[len - 1] == '\n') {
    buffer[--len] = '\0';
  }
  char *line = malloc(len + 1);
  if (line) {
    memcpy(line, buffer, len + 1);
  }
  return line;
}
```

Comment: Nice, but this would become tricky if (or when) OP wants `getInfo` to also return data for the other arguments.

Comment: @AdrianMole Fair point.  The return value could indicate the success/fail and references to data could be passed in as you well answered.